# Bootstrap's Togglable Tabs - Removing outline / focus ?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Toggable Tabs from [Twitters Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs)

The problem I have, Even you can see from the example too. That when the user clicks the tab, The active tab has the dotted border around it.

I am using Firefox 11. Screenshot of the issue:

[image]

I am looking to get rid of that dotted border. Does anyone know how you do this?

Thanks

Comment: What dotted border? I can only see a line (which visually identifies the selected tab). What browser are you using?

Comment: I do not see any dotted border. It looks solid to me

Comment: @burhan I am using FireFox v11

Comment: Here is a screenshot I have taken : http://i42.tinypic.com/e8a9ur.png

Comment: You'll find approximately 160,000 answers to this question here: https://www.google.ca/search?aq=f&ix=seb&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=css+remove+dotted+outline

Comment: To be fair, I thought it was just a Boostrap thing as I'd not seen it before. Plus I'm not from Canada, so wouldnt use google.ca ;-)

Comment: +1 for treating my smartass comment with kindness. :)

Comment: Did someone observed that if you click on the tab, it will show dotted outline as long as you hold your mouse left button down. Though by applying solution mentioned in this page, it will go off after that. How to remove outline when mouse left button is down?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

try using `outline: 0;` on the link element. see [css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline](http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline)

```
//line 2576 of bootstrap.css
.nav-tabs > .active > a, .nav-tabs > .active > a:hover { 
outline: 0;
color: #555555;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-bottom-color: transparent;
cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: Thats the one. Never used the CSS for outline before. That'll do it cross browser too?

Comment: line nr is in nonminified file and Bootstrap v2.0.2

Comment: I think it's a firefox thing. The dotted line probably will not show in other browsers.

Comment: @Tim the `outline` property is available for all modern browsers, including ie8+

Comment: @Andres llich It's true, but firefox is the only one that shows a dotted border on any link. see: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/outline for complete outline property

Comment: @Tim they have different styles yes. Chromes outline is solid blue for example.

Comment: On some cases (not particularly this one, it helps setting a:focus {
 outline: 0;
}

Comment: Guys, this issue of dotted line around the selected tab is for IE11 also. Faced same issue, thanks @Tim for the solution. Issue resolved for me. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 12):

You mean the outline, you can remove it as follows:

```
.nav-tabs > .active > a, .nav-tabs > .active > a:hover {
  outline:none;
}
```

Though i would suggest you leave it in, since it is there in part to help people with disabilities and screen readers display your content properly, so you would be affecting usability by removing it.

Comment: This is correct and very important. If you do remove the outline property you MUST replace it with another style on :focus for links and interactive elements. Users who cannot (or prefer not to) navigate a page with the mouse need a visual indication of which element is currently in focus. This is an accessibility requirement.

Answer (score 6):

Use following CSS on your page:

```
html * {
    outline: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That focus border is an accessibility feature. By removing it, you are impeding some being able to access your site. By some, I mean people with disabilities.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FT5yZmFXEhA#t=412) helps get my point (he has a mobility disability). ([Here's it forwarded](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FT5yZmFXEhA#t=525) to when he carps on removing the border.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the sample below ;)

```
.nav > li > a {
    outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve the issue for Firefox and all other browsers, I would use the following CSS:

```
/* Remove dotted outline from image inputs */
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}

/* Remove dotted outline from all links */
a {
 outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, if you compile your CSS from Less, drop this code into your less files

```
.tab-focus() {
  outline: 0;
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

**The 'disabled' class or state itself is NOT for assistive devices.**

I don't know where that information came from but it is completely false.
'Disabled' is a **STATE** wherein the button or anchor is **NOT ENABLED**.  Meaning the user cannot click on it.  Or, clicking it triggers no action. People with disabilities are not affected in any way by use of this tag.  BTW- I am the web developer/designer for a non-profit that provides support and services to people with disabilities and I test my pages on a variety of devices, including screen readers and other assistive devices.

The class for a tab with focus is `.focus` and the class for the active tab is `.active`.

Designing for accessibility is crucial so always check your code with a W3C-compliant validator (like https://validator.w3.org/).  Occasionally, I've had to manually control the tab or arrow order for tabs on a site via JavaScript but, generally, Bootstrap handles it pretty well.

**Example:**
I use the `.disabled` class for web forms all the time.  I have the Submit button disabled until all the required fields contain the proper information.  Then, simply remove the `.disabled` class and allow them to submit.

That said, you **do** need to include a border on focused/hover items for assistive devices.  This allows the user to be able to track what they are 'hovering' over on your site.  As mentioned above, you can restyle it to better fit your design or whatever but make sure you have something to indicate focus.

If anyone has countering info on this I'd be interested in reading it.

Comment: It's only useful in case when you're using a keyboard to move around or any other assistive device. I wish that could be turned on only when pressing a tab key and stay off when the majority of users are using a mouse or a touch screen