# Bootstrap example page not showing focus outline on tabs. How to get this behaviour

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When I visit the bootstrap examples page here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

I can click on the tabs and a blue focus outline (in chrome) does not appear. This is the behaviour I want. The same interaction (clicking a tab) in my application shows the blue outline.

I know there are several easy fixes ([Bootstrap's Togglable Tabs - Removing outline / focus ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789949/bootstraps-togglable-tabs-removing-outline-focus)) to this problem (changing the css to outline: 0 for anchors), but what I can't figure out is why the bootstrap example works (doesn't outline after clicking) and mine doesn't. When I select the tabs anchor tag in dev tools, this is the css I see applied:

```
.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
color: #555;
cursor: default;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
color: #555;
cursor: default;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
color: #555;
cursor: default;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.nav-tabs>li>a:hover {
border-color: #eee #eee #ddd;
}
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #eee;
}
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #eee;
}
.nav-tabs>li>a {
margin-right: 2px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
.nav>li>a {
position: relative;
display: block;
padding: 10px 15px;
}
a:focus {
outline: thin dotted;
outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
outline-offset: -2px;
}
a:focus, a:hover {
color: #23527c;
text-decoration: underline;
}
a:focus, a:hover {
color: #23527c;
text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active, a:hover {
outline: 0;
}
a {
color: #337ab7;
text-decoration: none;
}
a {
background-color: transparent;
}
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheeta:-webkit-any-link {
color: -webkit-link;
text-decoration: underline;
cursor: auto;
}
user agent stylesheet:focus {
outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}
```

Of particular interest is that 'a:focus' specifies the outline attribute, yet I don't see the outline after clicking the tab. I've also verified that the anchor is set to focus. If I use the "Toggle Element State" feature in Chrome Dev Tools and check "focus", the blue outline appears.

The styles applied to my application's bootstrap tabs are the same, yet I see the blue outline after clicking the tab.

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/2VmmW/ (I didn't create this, just googled Bootstrap tabs  jsfiddle). This matches the bootstrap example. It's just as easy to view this behaviour using dev tools.

Comment: i saw the demo on the bootstrap site but since you say it's not working on your site i wanted to see what you're doing specifically.  hence the request for a fiddle of YOUR code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to share that code directly. I can't seem to compartmentalize it in a fiddle. Regardless of my code though, the bootstrap example should technically show the blueline after a tab click; the element is focused, and the css for that element shows a styling that suggests it would be outlined in blue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue too. Odd how it only happens on certain browsers. I didn't have this issue with Chrome or Safari but it was happening on Firefox and IE11. This is what worked for me.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  outline: none;
}
```